# Flink stream not finishing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am settings up a flink stream processor using kafka and elasticsearch. I want to replay my data, but when i set the parallelism to more than 1, It does not finish the program I believe this to be because that only one message is seen by the kafka stream to be identified as the end of the stream.

```java
    public CustomSchema(Date _endTime) {
        endTime = _endTime;
    }

@Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(CustomTopicWrapper nextElement) {
        if (this.endTime != null && nextElement.messageTime.getTime() >= this.endTime.getTime()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

is there a way to tell all threads on the flink consumer group to end once one thread has completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you implemented your own SourceFunction use the `cancel` method like this example shows from the Flink [SourceFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SourceFunction.html#run-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction.SourceContext-). the class [FlinkKafkaConsumerBase](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.html#run-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction.SourceContext-) also has the cancel method.