# Finish Flink Program After end of all Kafka Consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am setting up a minimal example here, where I have N streams (100 in the example below) from N Kakfa topics.

I want to finish each stream when it sees a "EndofStream" message.
When all streams are finished, I expected the Flink Program to gracefully finish.
This is true when parallelism is set to 1, but does not happen in general.

From [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60723393/flink-stream-not-finishing), it seems like not all threads of kafka consumer group end.

[Others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44247452/3005132) have suggested to throw an exception. However, the program will terminate at the first exception and would not wait for all the streams to finish.

I am also adding a minimal python program to add messages to kafka topics for reproducibility. Please fill in the `<IP>:<PORT>` in each program.

```
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        String outputPath = "file://" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/out/output";

        Properties kafkaProps = null;
        kafkaProps = new Properties();
        String brokers = "<IP>:<PORT>";
        kafkaProps.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", brokers);
        kafkaProps.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");


        ArrayList<FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>> consumersList = new ArrayList<FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>>();
        ArrayList<DataStream<String>> streamList = new ArrayList<DataStream<String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            consumersList.add(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>(Integer.toString(i),
                        new SimpleStringSchema() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean isEndOfStream(String nextElement) {
                                if (nextElement.contains("EndofStream")) {
                                    // throw new RuntimeException("End of Stream");       
                                    return true;
                                } else { 
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        , kafkaProps));
            consumersList.get(i).setStartFromEarliest();
            streamList.add(env.addSource(consumersList.get(i)));
            streamList.get(i).writeAsText(outputPath + Integer.toString(i), WriteMode.OVERWRITE);
        }

        // execute program
        env.execute("Flink Streaming Java API Skeleton");
```

Python 3 Program

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='<IP>:<PORT>')

for i in range(100): # Channel Number
    for j in range(100): # Message Number
        message = "Message: " + str(j) + " going on channel: " + str(i)
        producer.send(str(i), str.encode(message))

    message = "EndofStream on channel: " + str(i)
    producer.send(str(i), str.encode(message))


producer.flush()
```

Changing this line: `streamList.add(env.addSource(consumersList.get(i)));` to `streamList.add(env.addSource(consumersList.get(i)).setParallelism(1));` also does the job, but then Flink places all the consumers to the same physical machine.

I would like the consumers to be distributed as well.

flink-conf.yaml

```
parallelism.default: 2
cluster.evenly-spread-out-slots: true
```

Last resort to write each topic in separate file and use file as a source instead of kafka consumer.
The end-goal is to test how much time flink takes to process certain workloads for certain programs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `cancel` method from [FlinkKafkaConsumerBase](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.html#cancel--) which is the parent class of `FlinkKafkaConsumer`.

> public void cancel() Description copied from interface: SourceFunction
> Cancels the source. Most sources will have a while loop inside the
> SourceFunction.run(SourceContext) method. The implementation needs to
> ensure that the source will break out of that loop after this method
> is called. A typical pattern is to have an "volatile boolean
> isRunning" flag that is set to false in this method. That flag is
> checked in the loop condition.
>
> When a source is canceled, the executing thread will also be
> interrupted (via Thread.interrupt()). The interruption happens
> strictly after this method has been called, so any interruption
> handler can rely on the fact that this method has completed. It is
> good practice to make any flags altered by this method "volatile", in
> order to guarantee the visibility of the effects of this method to any
> interruption handler.
>
> Specified by: cancel in interface SourceFunction

---

You are right. It is necessary to use the `SimpleStringSchema`. This was based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44247452/2096986. Take a look on this example. First I sent the string `Flink code we saw also works in a cluster` and the Kafka consumer consumes the message. Then I send `SHUTDOWNDDDDDDD` which also has no effect to finish the stream. Finally, I sent `SHUTDOWN` and the stream job is finalized. See the logs below the program.

```
package org.sense.flink.examples.stream.kafka;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;

public class KafkaConsumerQuery {

    public KafkaConsumerQuery() throws Exception {

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");

        FlinkKafkaConsumer myConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer(java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("test"),
                new MySimpleStringSchema(), properties);

        DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(myConsumer);
        stream.print();

        System.out.println("Execution plan >>>\n" + env.getExecutionPlan());
        env.execute(KafkaConsumerQuery.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    private static class MySimpleStringSchema extends SimpleStringSchema {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private final String SHUTDOWN = "SHUTDOWN";

        @Override
        public String deserialize(byte[] message) {

            return super.deserialize(message);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEndOfStream(String nextElement) {
            if (SHUTDOWN.equalsIgnoreCase(nextElement)) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.isEndOfStream(nextElement);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new KafkaConsumerQuery();
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
2020-07-02 16:39:59,025 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=test] Discovered group coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
3> Flink code we saw also works in a cluster. To run this code in a cluster
3> SHUTDOWNDDDDDDD
2020-07-02 16:40:27,973 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (3/4) (5f47c2b3f55c5eb558484d49fb1fcf0e) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
2020-07-02 16:40:27,973 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Freeing task resources for Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (3/4) (5f47c2b3f55c5eb558484d49fb1fcf0e).
2020-07-02 16:40:27,974 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for task Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (3/4) (5f47c2b3f55c5eb558484d49fb1fcf0e) [FINISHED]
2020-07-02 16:40:27,975 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor            - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FINISHED to JobManager for task Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (3/4) 5f47c2b3f55c5eb558484d49fb1fcf0e.
2020-07-02 16:40:27,979 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (3/4) (5f47c2b3f55c5eb558484d49fb1fcf0e) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
```

Comment: Where to call this function? We don't have access to `FlinkKafkaConsumer` object in `isEndOfStream` function

Comment: just extend this function `YourConsumer extends FlinkKafkaConsumer`

Comment: or thinking better you can call `cancel()` when you receive the string `EndofStream`, because `cancel()` is a method of the super class.

Comment: As you said, `cancel()` is part of super class, and the check for `isEndOfStream` is done by a private variable so extending the class does not seem like the right idea. The second suggestion to call `cancel()` when we receive `EndOfStream` is also a challenge as `FlinkKafkaConsumer` objects are not part of stream. I don't know any way to pass the consumer objects to the stream, but I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: I added an example using `SimpleStringSchema` and I change the return value of the method `isEndOfStream()`

Comment: Your example is logically not different than mine. They both end stream when matches the if-condition. Flink execution does not terminate if parallelism is set greater than 1.

Comment: I also tried once to place two consumers in diferent TM but I couldnt. Flink understands that it is best for the firsts operators on the same phase to be on the same TM if there is slots available.